# Why Binary Cross Entropy is more suitable than Categorical Cross Entropy in multi label classification?

Tags: neural-networks, classification, loss-functions, cross-entropy, multilabel

I found this [answers](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/410165/294962). But, I don't get fully. If I have three labels in multi label classification task, did BCE produce 3 separate outputs? Why we shouldn't use CCE?

In this [Facebook work](https://research.fb.com/publications/exploring-the-limits-of-weakly-supervised-pretraining/) they claim that, despite being counter-intuitive, Categorical Cross-Entropy loss, or Softmax loss worked better than Binary Cross-Entropy loss in their multi-label classification problem.

Comment: The paper you cite is about a special case of weakly supervised training, not a typical classification problem where samples taking on multiple labels.